# How to seperate code blocks in python using visual studio code?

Tags: python

I am used to coding in SQL where I can use the ';' symbol to separate two pieces of code and run them individually on one file. This makes testing specific parts of the code really easy. However, in python, I haven't found a way of testing bits of my code without having to create a new file and copy and pasting code. I am using VS Studio Code.

Kind Regards

Comment: I recommend starting by going through the basics of Python.

Comment: you mean run selection or current line?

Comment: Yes @DerekEden!

Comment: @starboi you can find the keyboard shortcut for this in the settings somewhere.. don't have my laptop but off the top of my head it's probably under file > preferences or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Use [functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Functions are a good way of encapsulating blocks of code that you want to run repeatedly or in a specific context. For your application, you could do:

```
def firstPieceOfCode():
    # do first job when called
    ...

def secondPieceOfCode():
    # do second job when called
    ...

secondPieceOfCode() # only do second job for now
```